# How to split and extract each tagname from the list of tags which is in the json data?

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

```
      "tags" : "['x', 'y', 'z']"
```

I want to extract each element and add each element to a tag table like

```
       tag1 = x
       tag2 = y 
       tag3 = z
```

I need to store each tag in tags table in different rows for a event.

```
     table: Event
       id, title, ...

     table: Tag
       Tagid, eventid, tagname
```

Tags can vary for each event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or without eval:

```
t = {"tags" : "['x', 'y', 'z']"}
tags = [el.replace("'","").strip() for el in t['tags'][1:-1].split(',')]

# Basic string splitting:
tags = t['tags'].split(',')

# To replace a character in a string, like "z"
"a123".replace("a", "b") => "b123

# To strip whitespace:
"  Wow  ".strip() => "Wow"

# Then, a list comprehension to loop through elements of an array and put them in new array:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [i+1 for i in x]  =>  [2, 3, 4]

# All together, this becomes
tags = [el.replace("'","").strip() for el in t['tags'][1:-1].split(',')]
```

Some say eval is evil, because it's subject to code injection, and therefore possibly unpredictable.  But as long as you trust the input, it should be okay.  Using `ast.literal_eval` is much better than eval, as it only evaluates to basic types, and so you don't have to worry about the code injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> t = {"tags" : "['x', 'y', 'z']"}
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(t['tags'])
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

And now it's a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Iterate over them and use the model manager to create the models.

Comment: How to do that?I have 
            obj = Tags(event_id = eventobj.pk, tags = tags)

How to insert each tag value by iterating over the list and saving in the model simultaneously.

Sorry I am beginner.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

from answer given by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I am able to change it into list as below:

```
     tags = ast.literal_eval(tags)  #converted to the list

     ##Stored the tags with event_id in the tags table. 
     eventobj = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
     for i in range(len(tags)):
        tagsobj = Tags.objects.create(name = tags[i], event_id = eventobj.pk)
     tagsobj.save()
```